cURL не возвращает файл
Есть URL адрес с портом. При вставке его в адресную строку браузера - требуемый фал отображается. При запросе его с помощью file_get_contents - файл возвращается. Но при запросе с помощью cURL файл не возвращается. curl_errno возвращает 3, curl_error ошибку не возвращает.
Код:
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, '2096');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

Пробовал убрать порт из адреса - не помогло. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём ошибка.
Адрес указать не могу по соображениям конфиденциальности.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php#103128 - пишет что формат url неправильный. Может нужно urlencode($url)
